# What is Plan B for when heroku goes down on your production app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This question is inspired by this recent outage:
https://status.heroku.com/incident/212

There doesn't seem to be much I can do here. I can't push at all, and pushing seemed to be what broke it in the first place. AFAIK, I can't switch over to a new server deployed on aws or elsewhere without fiddling with the DNS records. What should I do?

Comment: You could switch to AWS _before_ the next outage ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use an "all-in-one" service like Heroku you accept and understand than, in case of this kind of issue, you're in their hands and there's nothing you can do.

You can keep a backup system configured elsewhere but, from my point of view, this is a waste of time and resources because:

- it requires you to configure and clone all Heroku settings and features
- it's a double work
- in case of issues, the only way to redirect the traffic to your app is to change DNS settings. The change requires DNS changes to propagate
- if you can clone Heroku features, you might not want to use Heroku at all

It's a good idea to have an off-site backup of your application, database and features. But on the other side, these issues are the trade off of using this kind of services.

Answer (score 1):

The only real thing you could do would be to not rely on a single service provider for your application. This means that you would need to break out the DNS from the hosting platform so that you can re-point to a different platform (such as AWS).

Depending on your hosting platform, there are different options, but in a nutshell, the key is to reduce single points of failure and have plans in place to switch over when things to fail.